# plotting dual y axes in R for Date (as x axis), start time (y1 axis on left) and temperature (y2 axis on right) in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a dual y axes graphs in R using ggplot2. I know there are couple of detailed tutorials that shows how this is done. But what I am trying to achieve is little different. I want to plot x axis as Dates, y axis (left) as Start date time, y axis (right) as water temperature. I have seen similar graphs before but with dates its hard to do. You can see below what I have and image of so far what I have done. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
    tempdata<-read.table(text="Date Trip TripStartTime TripEndTime WaterTemperature
                 11/13/16   PM  13:00   16:00   13.43333333
                 11/13/16   PM  13:00   16:00   13.43333333
                 11/13/16   PM  13:00   16:00   12.97222222
                 11/19/16   PM  13:00   16:00   12.77777778
                 11/19/16   PM  13:00   16:00   0
                 11/19/16   PM  13:00   16:00   12.58333333
                 11/19/16   PM  13:00   16:00   12.58333333
                 11/25/16   PL  6:00    18:00   0
                 11/25/16   PL  6:00    18:00   0
                 11/25/16   PL  6:00    18:00   13.67777778", header=TRUE)

    tempdata$startdatetime <- paste(tempdata$Date,tempdata$TripStartTime, sep = " ")
    tempdata$enddatetime <- paste(tempdata$Date,tempdata$TripEndTime, sep = " ")
    tempdata$starthm <- format(tempdata$TripStartTime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
    tempdata$endhm <- format(tempdata$TripEndTime, format = "%H:%M:%S")
    tempdata$WaterTemperature<- as.numeric(as.character( tempdata$WaterTemperature ))

    str(tempdata)
    View(tempdata)
    tempdata<-data.frame(tempdata)

    attach(tempdata)

    plot.new()

    library(ggplot2)
    p1<- ggplot(tempdata, aes(startdatetime, WaterTemperature)) + 
    geom_point(color="red", size=0.5)+theme(axis.title.x=element_text("Start Time"),
                             axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                             axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    p2<- ggplot(tempdata, aes(enddatetime, WaterTemperature)) + 
    geom_point(color="blue", size=0.5)+ theme(axis.title.x=element_text("End Time"),
                              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                              axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    p3<-ggplot(tempdata, aes(Date, WaterTemperature)) + 
    geom_point(color="orange", size=0.5)+ theme(axis.title.x=element_text("Date"),
                              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                              axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
    p<- multiplot(p1, p2,p3, rows=3)
```

[image]

Comment: I also have forgot to add headers, evethough I said header=TRUE. Headers are as follows: Date  Trip  TripStartTime   TripEndTime WaterTemperature . Thanks.

Comment: To set the axis titles in ggplot2, use `xlab()` and `ylab()`, for example `+ xlab("Start Time")`.